# NUC8I3BEH does not boot after restart. Why?

Tags: boot

In January I was able to set up a NUC8I3BEH, with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

It's used as PLEX Server and ROON Server, nothing more, and everything was perfect until I probably did something wrong... Now, when the system has to reboot, it doesn't. It shows the INTEL NUC black screen and nothing more.

In order to restart the system I have to press the power button, and  Shift, in order to obtain the GRUB menu and use the advanced options for Ubuntu. At this point, I can boot the system and everything works fine.

Is it a NUC problem or I have to check something into the Linux OS? I already performed a boot-repair from Ubuntu, but nothing has changed, so it could be something wrong in BIOS (NUC)?

Comment: 'Advanced options' suggests you are able to boot an older kernel? Which would imply that your current kernel is not OK. Boot the older kernel, try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and follow any instructions on failed or interrupted updates.

Comment: Thanks Adriaan, I'm really a newbie.

Comment: I did in my terminal the updates and then I checked this: lsb_release -dc; uname -m

Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Codename: bionic
x86_64 What can I do now?

Comment: Well, did you do the `sudo apt update` followed by the `sudo apt dist-upgrade`? (For this, you need to start a terminal, just like you did for the `lsb_release -d`.)

Comment: yes, I did both of them, but I got no further instruction or failed updates. And nothing changed performing a new reboot. I'd be happy just to identify the problem, hardware/bios NUC-wise, or software, linux-wise :-)

Comment: You wrote _everything was perfect until I probably did something wrong..._. We could try and chase 'a' problem (re-installing kernels, re-generate grub defaults, etc etc), but then we would be guessing. Maybe the best option is to wait for the next kernel update and try that. In other words, the problem (whatever it is) may go away in few weeks. Until that time keep booting an older kernel - your server should work OK.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: Hi, after today’s requested update, my Linux Nuc is safely rebooting, no issues! Thanks.